# How can I type this special character?

Tags: unicode, special-characters

[image: Snipped Image]

I've searched for many places (Latex special symbols and Unicode symbols), but couldn't find it.

Comment: How do you know the character is even typeable? It could just be an image inserted into text.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the Unicode [Two Button Mouse](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f5b0/index.htm). It has the Unicode code point `U+1F5B0`.

However, on my machine with a recent operation system,the missing character symbol is shown instead of the mouse.

What does it show for you between the brackets? >> 🖰 <<

Even though it's shown as the missing character symbol, you should be able to copy-paste it into a program that supports this Unicode character. It's still the code point U+1F5B0.

Comment: I can see the mouse on Windows 10. There are also one and three-button mice: 

Comment: Yes, on my Windows 10 machine it's visible. On my Mac (macos Mojave) it isn't. And on Windows 7 neither. So don't assume that it works for everybody.